# nodejs : error: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, return-value

I tried to do a callback because i need to call this function in another file but i dont undrestand what's wrong.

```
 calcul_energie =function(){
  Index.find(({date:{$gt:date_debut,$lt:date_fin}}),function(err, resulta){
  result=resulta;
   for(i=1;i<result.length;i++) 

        { Mesure.indexp1=result[i].indexp1;

             Mesure.energiep1=(( result[i].indexp1)-( result[i-1].indexp1));

             mesures=JSON.stringify(Mesure);

            return(mesures);
              }
              });
```

---

```
    var cal=function(pas_integration,callback)
     {
      return callback(pas_integration);

      };
```

---

```
   var calcule=function(date_deb, date_fin, pas)

    {

    var mesure_energie = require("./calcul.js");

    mesure_energie =cal(5,calcul_energie);
    console.log(mesure_energie);
    }
```

can you help please?
thanks

Comment: Somewhere (not in the code you included in the question) you call that function. Whatever call you pass as the callback argument isn't a function. But that just repeats what the error message says. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i didnt undrestand why the error in this line: callback(mesures);

Comment: Of course it is. That's the first time you *do anything* with the value (whatever it is, we can't tell that because you didn't include the code that defines it)

Comment: Please format and indent your code to make it properly readable here on this site.

Comment: Can you please post the code that imports and uses this module?

Comment: yes i rewrite all the code but i always have measures asundefined. you can see i repost the code . Can you please help me.!@EgidioCaprino  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must pass function definition as a callback.  Eg.

```
function myCallback(returnedMeasures) {
    // your code here
}
```

and use it to call your other function like this:

```
calcul(pas,myCallBack);
```

if that doesn't help please provide more complete example, including callback function definition and the way you call `calcul(...)` with that callback

Comment: thanks for your answer..For me all i need is to undrestand how to return the mesures. if i do return(measures) it return undefined and if i do a callback, it tell me callback is not a function. Maybei didnt undrestand how to use callback

Comment: your function looks fine and you are calling the callback correctly, the only thing I can think of is that your callback is something you didn't intend.  Maybe try putting `console.log(callback)` before `callback(measures)`.

Comment: i did it but it tell me the callback is undefined.